# Issues with setting query ranges on google charts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm fairly new to coding with google charts/javascript, and for some reason when I try to draw data from a spreadsheet I can't specify the range.I'm using a tiny example spreadsheet and it still won't work. My java code is below, and I've tried every url modification I could find. Using 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHeR6LetK5ztqvgIm53OpbNFjMttRICBBDR8j1yEAjg/edit#gid=0range=2:5'doesn't change the result.

Using 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHeR6LetK5ztqvgIm53OpbNFjMttRICBBDR8j1yEAjg/gviz/tq?range=2:5'won't generate a chart even though excluding the range will.

The whole java code is here, what am I doing wrong?:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['line', 'corechart', 'table']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var queryString =  encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, H, O, Q, R, U LIMIT 5 OFFSET 8');
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHeR6LetK5ztqvgIm53OpbNFjMttRICBBDR8j1yEAjg/edit#gid=0range=A1:C2' + queryString);
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {

  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();


  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Example Data'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      0: {
        axis: 'Miles'
      },
      1: {
        axis: 'Heartrate'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      y: {
        Miles: {
          label: 'Miles Run'
        },
        Heartrate: {
          label: 'Heart rate(BPM)'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function drawMaterialChart() {
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
    materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
  }
  drawMaterialChart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parameters on the url need to separated by --> `&`

e.g. --> `.../edit#gid=0&range=A1:C2`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['line', 'corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHeR6LetK5ztqvgIm53OpbNFjMttRICBBDR8j1yEAjg/edit#gid=0&range=A1:C2');
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {

  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();


  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Example Data'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      0: {
        axis: 'Miles'
      },
      1: {
        axis: 'Heartrate'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      y: {
        Miles: {
          label: 'Miles Run'
        },
        Heartrate: {
          label: 'Heart rate(BPM)'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function drawMaterialChart() {
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
    materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
  }
  drawMaterialChart();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note:** if you're going to include a query string,
the select statement needs to be within the range set on the url
currently, range only includes columns `A` thru `C`
but sql has `H, O, Q, R, U`

---

**EDIT**

drop the range and try using method `setQuery` to use a SQL statement...

```
query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C LIMIT 3');
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['line', 'corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHeR6LetK5ztqvgIm53OpbNFjMttRICBBDR8j1yEAjg/edit#gid=0');
  query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C LIMIT 3');  
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {

  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();


  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Example Data'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      0: {
        axis: 'Miles'
      },
      1: {
        axis: 'Heartrate'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      y: {
        Miles: {
          label: 'Miles Run'
        },
        Heartrate: {
          label: 'Heart rate(BPM)'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function drawMaterialChart() {
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
    materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
  }
  drawMaterialChart();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can't believe I forgot the & sign, but I'm noticing that even with the & sign it's still producing more points than the range of A1:C2 allows ie even in the example you showed C has 3 points when it should have 2, and when I extended the same logic to a sheet with 5 columns requesting only 3 it ignored the range.  How you you fix this?